# Too much space left (bible, xml and xsl-fo to pdf)

Tags: xml, space, xsl-fo

Good day,
I have a following problem (can be viewed here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDi/110 , from page 8-9,

There always remains a free space, which is actually unnecessarily not taken over.

What are the possibilities so that the text continues "smoothly" without space.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a combination of `widows` on the last block in Chapter 2 and the `keep-with-next.within-page="always"` on `CHAPTER`.

The `keep-with-next.within-page="always"` on `CHAPTER` means that there can't be a page break between Chapter 2 and Chapter 3, so some part of the end of Chapter 2 has to be on the same page as the start of Chapter 3.

The `widows` property (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#widows) specifies the minimum number of lines after a page break. The default is 2, which is why there's two lines of Chapter 2 before the start of Chapter 3 on page 9.

If you remove the `keep-with-next.within-page` (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDi/112), then two lines in the second column on page 5 move back to the first column, and you get four lines of Chapter 3 on page 8. (I don't know why changing `keep-with-next.within-page` should affect column breaks in FOP. I also don't know why you would need another `keep-with-next.within-page` on `BIBLEBOOK`.)

Comment: Wow! Yes, unfortunately this is not my own code. But so it works well, which I can use for my benefit and case! Thank you very much!